# Melhorando modelagem em um sistema de pedidos

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, modelagem

Desenvolvi um sistema de pedido de comidas, mas tenho duvidas se a forma que modelei o banco de dados é a melhor em questão de performance e longevidade (como o sistema era se comportar com uma grande quantidade de dados).

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabelas:

- Pedidos
- Pedido_Items com os campos: PedidoID, ItemID
- Pedido_Item_SubItems com os campos: PedidoID, ItemID, SubItemID

Ou seja, quando um pedido é criado ele tem items que o compõe. Esses items são salvos no DB recebendo o ID do pedido que ele pertence. É possível que os items tenham SubItems (pensem em como um hamburguer pode ter alface, tomate, cebola), os SubItems recebem o ID do pedido e o ID do Item que ele pertence.

Com base nessa estrutura e pensando a longo prazo, teria uma tabela de Items e SubItems gigantesca. Na hora de gerar relatórios eu perderia muita performance para trazer essas informações ? 
Existe uma solução melhor ?

Pensei em salvar os Items e SubItems em JSON em um campo na tabela Pedidos, mas o meu serviço de host não disponibiliza um MYSQL tão atualizado.

Comment: eu faria apenas uma mudança, que seria remover `PedidoId` da tabela `Pedido_Item_Subitems`, pois você já tem essa informação na tabela `Pedido_items`. Em questão a performance , se você cria sua query de forma adequada, conseguirá o máximo de desempenho que o seu banco de dados permitir. Já que o seu modelo está correto pelas informações que você nos passou em sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, vou seguir o recomendado.